# Windows Phone 8 Set Navigate URI

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm setting up a series of buttons, one for each item in a table. What I need to do is set the Navigate parameter for each button, is there anyway I can set the following from the .cs code?:

```
<ec:NavigateToPageAction TargetPage="/MissionPage.xaml"/>
```

Here's the code I'm using to make the buttons:

```
foreach (string i in missionQ)
        {
            Button btn = new Button() { Content = "Run", Width=120, Height=90 };
            btn.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Right;
            btn.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
            btn.Margin = new Thickness(0, (100*x), 20, 0); }
```

Comment: so each string i in your foreach is a diffrent xaml for navigation?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this code in your Click event of the button

```
using System.Windows.Navigation;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MissionPage.xaml.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Ref: [NavigationService Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The way I would handle this is by, creating a new eventhandler for the tap event on each button. Pass i as reference to the function.

```
btn.Tap += functionToHandleTap(i);
```

In the function it self I would create a switch or if statement and then navigate based on the i parameter passed to funtionToHandleTap.

```
        private void functionToHandleTap(string i)
    {
        string naviString = string.Empty;

        if (i == "something")
        {
            naviString = "some xaml here";
        }
        else
        {
            naviString = "another xaml here";
        }

        _rootFrame.Navigate(new Uri(naviString, UriKind.Relative));
    }
```